# How do I get the current time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

How do I get the current time in Python?

Comment: please note, the most voted answers are for timezonoe-naive datetime, while we see that in production environment more and more services across the world are connected together and timezone-aware datetime become the required standard

Comment: This is a very valid point by @SławomirLenart and here is a quick tutorial showing [multiple ways to get the current time based on the timezone](https://www.codingeek.com/tutorials/python/current-time/)

Answer (score 3904, accepted):

Use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 6, 15, 8, 24, 78915)
>>> print(now)
2009-01-06 15:08:24.789150
```

For just the clock time without the date:

```
>>> now.time()
datetime.time(15, 8, 24, 78915)
>>> print(now.time())
15:08:24.789150
```

---

To save typing, you can import the `datetime` object from the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
```

Then remove the prefix `datetime.` from all of the above.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer covered timezones (maybe UTC as an example) and perhaps begin with time.time().

Comment: @Toskan the format was not part of the question, so it shouldn't be part of the answer. There's already a link provided to more documentation of the module which contains stuff like formatting.

Comment: Which version of Python was the original answer given in? Just typing `datetime.datetime.now()` in my Python 2.7 interactive console (IronPython hasn't updated yet) gives me the same behavior as the newer example using `print()` in the answer. I haven't successfully replicated what the original answer shows (datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 6, 15, 8, 24, 78915)). (Not that I really want to, the print() behavior is preferred, but I am curious.)

Comment: @BobVicktor: Python 2.7, 3.7 and 3.8 all give the same behaviour for me, not sure what you're seeing.

Comment: @HarleyHolcombe Hmm... maybe it is an IronPython thing? When I type `datetime.now()` on its own it prints it out the same was as your answer shows `print(datetime.now())`...

Comment: Consider `import datetime as dt` if you want to use other datetime modules, such as `datetime.time`.

Comment: @GregLindahl Timezone Aware: `datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC).astimezone()` ... Or, something similar, like the actual timezone where the system is located. Alternately, `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone()` or `datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone()` depending on the Python version and use case.

Answer (score 1207):

Use [`time.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html?highlight=time.strftime#time.strftime):

```
>>> from time import gmtime, strftime
>>> strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
'2009-01-05 22:14:39'
```

Comment: Is this better/worse than @ParaMeterz's answer below?  Why should we use the `time` module vs. the `datetime` module?

Comment: It doesn't return current hour of my computer.

Comment: This is UTC time, different from datetime module

Comment: @Saeed: Use the function `localtime()` instead of the `gmtime()` to get your local time.

Comment: @frank See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7479777/9382524) on `datetime` vs. `time`.

Comment: Note: `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` defaults to use `time.localtime()`. Also, `time.gmtime()` sets DST(daylight saving time) flag to 0, whereas `time.localtime()` sets DST flag to 1 if DST applies to that time.

Answer (score 856):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Example output: `'2013-09-18 11:16:32'`

See list of [`strftime` directives](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Answer (score 531):

Similar to [Harley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python/415519#415519), but use the `str()` function for a quick-n-dirty, slightly more human readable format:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> str(datetime.now())
'2011-05-03 17:45:35.177000'
```

Comment: @ppperry, then just simply assign a variable to Ray's answer - like: _myTime = str(datetime.now())_.

Comment: Not relevant; the "str" step is not within the scope of the question

Comment: @pppery Nor does the op say it isn't about getting a string of the time. The op doesn't say at all what they want to do with the time, so why is it a bad thing to show how to turn it in to a string? Most of the answers talk about getting a string from the time, so it appears to be a common use case, so why single out Ray's answer? What use is simply getting the time without knowing how to *do* anything with it? You can print it, or do math on it, and only a couple of the answers show how to do math on it, so I think printing/getting a string is a common use. ;-) (I know it is what I came for.)

Comment: The fact that this answer has more than 440 upvotes suggests that the minor addition of the string method _was_ useful to a lot of people.

Comment: The fact that 440 people were looking for content that is not an actual answer to the question does not make that content an answer to the question.

Comment: @pppery The fact that it is another way to answer the question which makes it  RELEVANT to other people who has a similar question to this question. So there is nothing wrong with this :)

Answer (score 526):

> ## How do I get the current time in Python?

### The `time` module

The `time` module provides functions that tell us the time in "seconds since the epoch" as well as other utilities.

```
import time
```

#### Unix Epoch Time

This is the format you should get timestamps in for saving in databases. It is a simple floating-point number that can be converted to an integer. It is also good for arithmetic in seconds, as it represents the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00, and it is memory light relative to the other representations of time we'll be looking at next:

```
>>> time.time()
1424233311.771502
```

This timestamp does not account for leap-seconds, so it's not linear - leap seconds are ignored. So while it is not equivalent to the international UTC standard, it is close, and therefore quite good for most cases of record-keeping.

This is not ideal for human scheduling, however. If you have a future event you wish to take place at a certain point in time, you'll want to store that time with a string that can be parsed into a `datetime` object or a serialized `datetime` object (these will be described later).

#### `time.ctime`

You can also represent the current time in the way preferred by your operating system (which means it can change when you change your system preferences, so don't rely on this to be standard across all systems, as I've seen others expect). This is typically user friendly, but doesn't typically result in strings one can sort chronologically:

```
>>> time.ctime()
'Tue Feb 17 23:21:56 2015'
```

You can hydrate timestamps into human readable form with `ctime` as well:

```
>>> time.ctime(1424233311.771502)
'Tue Feb 17 23:21:51 2015'
```

This conversion is also not good for record-keeping (except in text that will only be parsed by humans - and with improved Optical Character Recognition and Artificial Intelligence, I think the number of these cases will diminish).

### `datetime` module

The `datetime` module is also quite useful here:

```
>>> import datetime
```

#### `datetime.datetime.now`

The `datetime.now` is a class method that returns the current time. It uses the `time.localtime` without the timezone info (if not given, otherwise see timezone aware below). It has a representation (which would allow you to recreate an equivalent object) echoed on the shell, but when printed (or coerced to a `str`), it is in human readable (and nearly ISO) format, and the lexicographic sort is equivalent to the chronological sort:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 23, 43, 49, 94252)
>>> print(datetime.datetime.now())
2015-02-17 23:43:51.782461
```

#### datetime's `utcnow`

You can get a datetime object in UTC time, a global standard, by doing this:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 4, 53, 28, 394163)
>>> print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
2015-02-18 04:53:31.783988
```

UTC is a time standard that is nearly equivalent to the GMT timezone. (While GMT and UTC do not change for Daylight Savings Time, their users may switch to other timezones, like British Summer Time, during the Summer.)

#### datetime timezone aware

However, none of the datetime objects we've created so far can be easily converted to various timezones. We can solve that problem with the `pytz` module:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> then = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
>>> then
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 4, 55, 58, 753949, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Equivalently, in Python 3 we have the `timezone` class with a utc `timezone` instance attached, which also makes the object timezone aware (but to convert to another timezone without the handy `pytz` module is left as an exercise to the reader):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 22, 31, 56, 564191, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

And we see we can easily convert to timezones from the original UTC object.

```
>>> print(then)
2015-02-18 04:55:58.753949+00:00
>>> print(then.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')))
2015-02-17 23:55:58.753949-05:00
```

You can also make a naive datetime object aware with the `pytz` timezone `localize` method, or by replacing the tzinfo attribute (with `replace`, this is done blindly), but these are more last resorts than best practices:

```
>>> pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 6, 6, 29, 32285, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 6, 9, 30, 728550, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

The `pytz` module allows us to make our `datetime` objects timezone aware and convert the times to the hundreds of timezones available in the `pytz` module.

One could ostensibly serialize this object for UTC time and store *that* in a database, but it would require far more memory and be more prone to error than simply storing the Unix Epoch time, which I demonstrated first.

The other ways of viewing times are much more error-prone, especially when dealing with data that may come from different time zones. You want there to be no confusion as to which timezone a string or serialized datetime object was intended for.

If you're displaying the time with Python for the user, `ctime` works nicely, not in a table (it doesn't typically sort well), but perhaps in a clock. However, I personally recommend, when dealing with time in Python, either using Unix time, or a timezone aware UTC `datetime` object.

Comment: I think everyone can agree that `ctime` has got to be the weirdest way of formatting a datetime ever. Abbreviated day of the week and month, day of month, 24 hour h:m:s, and then a four digit year. Nerds that like to sort date strings, Americans, Europeans... everyone - yes, everyone - can find at least two things to be irritated about in that format. Although I'll use it because it's super easy.

Comment: As I say above regarding `ctime`: "You can also represent the current time in the way preferred by your operating system (which means it can change when you change your system preferences, so don't rely on this to be standard across all systems, as I've seen others expect). This is typically user friendly, but doesn't typically result in strings one can sort chronologically:"

Comment: This could be improved by adding a reference to [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo); pytz, although presend on many dependency specs, is outdated since Python 3.9.

Comment: I get a deprecation warning with `utcnow()`, the way to do it now is `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC)`

Comment: @Liam thanks for pointing out the deprecation warning, I'll update the answer soon on that.

Answer (score 157):

Do

```
from time import time

t = time()
```

- `t` - float number, good for time interval measurement.

There is some difference for Unix and Windows platforms.

Comment: My result on Windows 10 home was 1576095264.2682993 - for Windows, this might just give the time in seconds.

Answer (score 121):

```
>>> from time import gmtime, strftime
>>> strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X +0000", gmtime())
'Tue, 06 Jan 2009 04:54:56 +0000'
```

That outputs the current GMT in the specified format. There is also a [`localtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime) method.

This [page](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#module-time) has more details.

Answer (score 85):

The previous answers are all good suggestions, but I find it easiest to use `ctime()`:

```
In [2]: from time import ctime
In [3]: ctime()
Out[3]: 'Thu Oct 31 11:40:53 2013'
```

This gives a nicely formatted string representation of the current local time.

Comment: This is actually very efficient way to do it. 
Importing just a function (instead of whole class) consumes less time-space and even helps avoid any potential name-confusion for other functions in the class or stack.

Answer (score 80):

The quickest way is:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
'20130924'
```

Answer (score 66):

If you need current time as a `time` object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.time(now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
datetime.time(11, 23, 44)
```

Answer (score 51):

You can use the `time` module:

```
>>> import time
>>> print(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
06/02/2015
```

The use of the capital `Y` gives the full year, and using `y` would give `06/02/15`.

You could also use the following code to give a more lengthy time:

```
>>> time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
'Fri, 06 Feb 2015 17:45:09'
```

Answer (score 48):

`.isoformat()` is in the documentation, but not yet here
(this is mighty similar to @Ray Vega's answer):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
'2013-06-24T20:35:55.982000'
```

Answer (score 43):

Why not ask the [U.S. Naval Observatory](http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl), the official timekeeper of the United States Navy?

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
print(tree.xpath('//html//body//h3//pre/text()')[1])
```

If you live in the D.C. area (like me) the latency might not be too bad...

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 While you are correct that the other answers assume that your computer already knows the correct time, this answer assumes that the computer has a connection to the internet,  that you are in the U.S., and that they will never take down that file/alter the link. Far more assumptions in this answer than accepted. Still clever none the less

Comment: Excellent to have another source for time than the builtin clock! Even a good alternative to the more logical choice of NTP.

Comment: Site is no longer available
$ curl http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: tycho.usno.navy.mil

Answer (score 43):

Using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.now.html) to get the current time, kind of overkilling the problem at hand:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.datetime.now())
print(pd.datetime.now().date())
print(pd.datetime.now().year)
print(pd.datetime.now().month)
print(pd.datetime.now().day)
print(pd.datetime.now().hour)
print(pd.datetime.now().minute)
print(pd.datetime.now().second)
print(pd.datetime.now().microsecond)
```

Output:

```
2017-09-22 12:44:56.092642
2017-09-22
2017
9
22
12
44
56
92693
```

Comment: This method will be deprecated in future versions of pandas. Use the datetime module instead.

Answer (score 35):

if you are using numpy already then directly you can use numpy.datetime64() 
function.

```
import numpy as np
str(np.datetime64('now'))
```

for only date:

```
str(np.datetime64('today'))
```

or, if you are using pandas already then you can use pandas.to_datetime() function

```
import pandas as pd
str(pd.to_datetime('now'))
```

or,

```
str(pd.to_datetime('today'))
```

Answer (score 33):

This is what I ended up going with:

```
>>>from time import strftime
>>>strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
01/09/2015 13:11
```

Also, this table is a necessary reference for choosing the appropriate format codes to get the date formatted just the way you want it (from Python "datetime" documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)).

[image: strftime format code table]

Comment: `strftime(time_format)` returns the current local time as a string that corresponds to the given `time_format`. Note: `time.strftime()` and `datetime.strftime()` support different directive sets e.g., [`%z` is not supported by `time.strftime()` on Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Comment: Is it better practice to use datetime instead of time?

Comment: Many `time` module functions are thin wrappers around corresponding C functions. `datetime` is a higher level and it is usually more portable.

Answer (score 32):

`datetime.now()` returns the current time as a naive datetime object that represents time in the local timezone. That value may be ambiguous e.g., during DST transitions ("fall back"). To avoid ambiguity either UTC timezone should be used:

```
from datetime import datetime

utc_time = datetime.utcnow()
print(utc_time) # -> 2014-12-22 22:48:59.916417
```

Or a timezone-aware object that has the corresponding timezone info attached (Python 3.2+):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()
print(now) # -> 2014-12-23 01:49:25.837541+03:00
```

Comment: FYI, it is not recommended to use `datetime.utcnow()` to represent the current time in UTC as that still returns a 'naive' datetime object -- instead, it is recommended to use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` as that returns an 'aware' datetime object.

See the Python docs for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow

Comment: @Seth notice that the Python 3.2+ solution uses `timezone.utc` already. Perhaps, now that Python 2.7 is EOLed the naive-datetime may be dropped

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that was there purely for compatibility with Python 2.7 -- perhaps that should be clarified in the post? At least to me, it seemed like this post was implying that both the naive and aware methods were (still) equally acceptable ways to get the UTC time, which is why I pointed out that that's not what Python's (latest) documentation says.

Answer (score 25):

```
>>> import datetime, time
>>> time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S:%MS", time.localtime())
>>> print time
'00:21:38:20S'
```

Comment: I think you mean to say "datetime.now().strftime(...)"

Comment: yes it can be done as you said. "datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S:%MS")"

Comment: %MS does not give you milliseconds!!

Answer (score 25):

```
import datetime
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()

date = date_time.date()  # Gives the date
time = date_time.time()  # Gives the time

print date.year, date.month, date.day
print time.hour, time.minute, time.second, time.microsecond
```

Do `dir(date)` or any variables including the package. You can get all the attributes and methods associated with the variable.

Comment: @snofty and @user1016274, if
`import datetime` then it is `datetime.datetime.now()`\n
if `from datetime import datetime` then it is `datetime.now()`

Answer (score 25):

This question doesn't need a new answer just for the sake of it ... a shiny new-ish toy/module, however, is enough justification.  That being the [Pendulum library](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/), which appears to do the sort of things which arrow attempted, except without the inherent flaws and bugs which beset arrow.

For instance, the answer to the original question:

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> print(pendulum.now())
2018-08-14T05:29:28.315802+10:00
>>> print(pendulum.now('utc'))
2018-08-13T19:29:35.051023+00:00
```

There's a lot of standards which need addressing, including multiple RFCs and ISOs, to worry about.  Ever get them mixed up; not to worry, take a little look into `dir(pendulum.constants)` There's a bit more than RFC and ISO formats there, though.

When we say local, though what do we mean?  Well I mean:

```
>>> print(pendulum.now().timezone_name)
Australia/Melbourne
>>>
```

Presumably most of the rest of you mean somewhere else.

And on it goes.  Long story short: Pendulum attempts to do for date and time what requests did for HTTP.  It's worth consideration, particularly for both its ease of use and extensive documentation.

Answer (score 22):

By default, `now()` function returns output in the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MS` format. Use the below sample script to get the current date and time in a Python script and print results on the screen. Create file `getDateTime1.py` with the below content.

```
import datetime

currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
print (str(currentDT))
```

The output looks like below:

```
2018-03-01 17:03:46.759624
```

Answer (score 21):

Try the arrow module from http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/:

```
import arrow
arrow.now()
```

Or the UTC version:

```
arrow.utcnow()
```

To change its output, add .format():

```
arrow.utcnow().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ')
```

For a specific timezone:

```
arrow.now('US/Pacific')
```

An hour ago:

```
arrow.utcnow().replace(hours=-1)
```

Or if you want the gist.

```
arrow.get('2013-05-11T21:23:58.970460+00:00').humanize()
>>> '2 years ago'
```

Comment: beware that `arrow.now('Time/Zone')` may fail for some timezones (`arrow` uses [`dateutil` that has broken utc -> local conversions](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/112) that are used inside `arrow.now()`. Note: [`pytz` has no such issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31886808/4279). Also, [there are other timezone-related issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087218/parse-date-and-time-from-string-with-time-zone-using-arrow/28095706#comment44593877_28095706)

Answer (score 19):

To get exactly **3** **decimal points** for milliseconds `11:34:23.751` run this:

```
def get_time_str(decimal_points=3):
        return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) + '.%d' % (time.time() % 1 * 10**decimal_points)
```

**More context:**

I want to get the time with milliseconds. A simple way to get them:

```
import time, datetime

print(datetime.datetime.now().time())                         # 11:20:08.272239

# Or in a more complicated way
print(datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat())             # 11:20:08.272239
print(datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')) # 11:20:08.272239

# But do not use this:
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f", time.localtime()), str)    # 11:20:08.%f
```

But I want **only milliseconds**, right? The shortest way to get them:

```
import time

time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) + '.%d' % (time.time() % 1 * 1000)
# 11:34:23.751
```

Add or remove zeroes from the last multiplication to adjust number of decimal points, or just:

```
def get_time_str(decimal_points=3):
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) + '.%d' % (time.time() % 1 * 10**decimal_points)
```

Comment: This works in Python 3:
    time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) + '.{}'.format(int(time.time()  % 1 * 1000))

Answer (score 19):

**Current time of a timezone**

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)
print("NY time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

tz_London = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
datetime_London = datetime.now(tz_London)
print("London time:", datetime_London.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

tz_India = pytz.timezone('Asia/India')
datetime_India = datetime.now(tz_India)
print("India time:", datetime_India.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

#list timezones
pytz.all_timezones
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use this function to get the time (unfortunately it doesn't say AM or PM):

```
def gettime():
    from datetime import datetime
    return ((str(datetime.now())).split(' ')[1]).split('.')[0]
```

To get the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to merge later, you can use these functions:

*Hour:*

```
def gethour():
    from datetime import datetime
    return (((str(datetime.now())).split(' ')[1]).split('.')[0]).split(':')[0]
```

*Minute:*

```
def getminute():
    from datetime import datetime
    return (((str(datetime.now())).split(' ')[1]).split('.')[0]).split(':')[1]
```

*Second:*

```
def getsecond():
    from datetime import datetime
    return (((str(datetime.now())).split(' ')[1]).split('.')[0]).split(':')[2]
```

*Millisecond:*

```
def getmillisecond():
    from datetime import datetime
    return (str(datetime.now())).split('.')[1]
```

Answer (score 18):

If you just want the current timestamp in ms (for example, to measure execution time), you can also use the "timeit" module:

```
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
do_stuff_you_want_to_measure()
end_time = timeit.default_timer()
print("Elapsed time: {}".format(end_time - start_time))
```

Answer (score 18):

You can  try the following

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)
```

or

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%Y-%b-%d, %A %I:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 15):

Because no one has mentioned it yet, and this is something I ran into recently... a pytz timezone's fromutc() method combined with datetime's utcnow() is the best way I've found to get a useful current time (and date) in any timezone.

```
from datetime import datetime

import pytz


JST = pytz.timezone("Asia/Tokyo")


local_time = JST.fromutc(datetime.utcnow())
```

If all you want is the time, you can then get that with `local_time.time()`.

Comment: Surprisingly, All the above answers didnt mention Time zones. you should also include strftime to get the format you wanted.

Comment: I didn't include that since it's already been covered in other answers (and display formatting wasn't part of the question).

Answer (score 14):

```
import datetime

todays_date = datetime.date.today()
print(todays_date)
>>> 2019-10-12

# adding strftime will remove the seconds
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
print(current_time)
>>> 23:38
```

Answer (score 13):

**Method1: Getting Current Date and Time from system datetime**

The **datetime** module supplies classes for manipulating dates and times.

> Code

```
from datetime import datetime,date

print("Date: "+str(date.today().year)+"-"+str(date.today().month)+"-"+str(date.today().day))
print("Year: "+str(date.today().year))
print("Month: "+str(date.today().month))
print("Day: "+str(date.today().day)+"\n")

print("Time: "+str(datetime.today().hour)+":"+str(datetime.today().minute)+":"+str(datetime.today().second))
print("Hour: "+str(datetime.today().hour))
print("Minute: "+str(datetime.today().minute))
print("Second: "+str(datetime.today().second))
print("MilliSecond: "+str(datetime.today().microsecond))
```

> Output will be like

```
Date: 2020-4-18
Year: 2020
Month: 4
Day: 18

Time: 19:30:5
Hour: 19
Minute: 30
Second: 5
MilliSecond: 836071
```

**Method2: Getting Current Date and Time if Network is available**

**urllib** package helps us to handle the url's that means webpages. Here we collects data from the webpage http://just-the-time.appspot.com/ and parses **dateime** from the webpage using the package **dateparser**.

> Code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import dateparser

time_url = urlopen(u'http://just-the-time.appspot.com/')
datetime = time_url.read().decode("utf-8", errors="ignore").split(' ')[:-1]
date = datetime[0]
time = datetime[1]

print("Date: "+str(date))
print("Year: "+str(date.split('-')[0]))
print("Month: "+str(date.split('-')[1]))
print("Day: "+str(date.split('-')[2])+'\n')

print("Time: "+str(time))
print("Hour: "+str(time.split(':')[0]))
print("Minute: "+str(time.split(':')[1]))
print("Second: "+str(time.split(':')[2]))
```

> Output will be like

```
Date: 2020-04-18
Year: 2020
Month: 04
Day: 18

Time: 14:17:10
Hour: 14
Minute: 17
Second: 10
```

**Method3: Getting Current Date and Time from Local Time of the Machine**

Python's **time** module provides a function for getting local time from the number of seconds elapsed since the epoch called localtime(). **ctime()** function takes seconds passed since epoch as an argument and returns a string representing local time.

> Code

```
from time import time, ctime
datetime = ctime(time()).split(' ')

print("Date: "+str(datetime[4])+"-"+str(datetime[1])+"-"+str(datetime[2]))
print("Year: "+str(datetime[4]))
print("Month: "+str(datetime[1]))
print("Day: "+str(datetime[2]))
print("Week Day: "+str(datetime[0])+'\n')

print("Time: "+str(datetime[3]))
print("Hour: "+str(datetime[3]).split(':')[0])
print("Minute: "+str(datetime[3]).split(':')[1])
print("Second: "+str(datetime[3]).split(':')[2])
```

> Output will be like

```
Date: 2020-Apr-18
Year: 2020
Month: Apr
Day: 18
Week Day: Sat

Time: 19:30:20
Hour: 19
Minute: 30
Second: 20
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do so using ctime():

```
from time import time, ctime
t = time()
ctime(t)
```

output:

`Sat Sep 14 21:27:08 2019`

These outputs are different because the timestamp returned by `ctime()` depends on your geographical location.

Answer (score 11):

try this one:-

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
import datetime
date_time = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()
date,time = date_time
```

**date** will print date and **time** will print time.

Answer (score 9):

The following is what I use to get the time without having to format. Some people don't like the split method, but it is useful here:

```
from time import ctime
print ctime().split()[3]
```

It will print in HH:MM:SS format.

Answer (score 9):

This question is for Python but since Django is one of the most widely used frameworks for Python, its important to note that if you are using Django you can always use `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`. The former is timezone 'aware' while the latter is not.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26950056/1526703) and the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) for details and rationale behind `timezone.now()`.

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

Answer (score 8):

This is so simple.
Try:

```
import datetime
date_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
date = date_time.split()[0]
time = date_time.split()[1]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
from time import ctime

// Day {Mon,Tue,..}
print ctime().split()[0]
// Month {Jan, Feb,..}
print ctime().split()[1]
// Date {1,2,..}
print ctime().split()[2]
// HH:MM:SS
print ctime().split()[3]
// Year {2018,..}
print ctime().split()[4]
```

When you call `ctime()` it will convert seconds to string in format `'Day Month Date HH:MM:SS Year'` (for example: `'Wed January 17 16:53:22 2018'`), then you call `split()` method that will make a list from your string `['Wed','Jan','17','16:56:45','2018']` (default delimeter is space).

Brackets are used to 'select' wanted argument in list.

One should call just one code line. One should not call them like I did, that was just an example, because in some cases you will get different values, rare but not impossible cases.

Comment: You might also want to explain why extracting parts from multiple calls of `ctime()` like that (using "current" time at each call) will not necessarily give a useful value in combination with each other.

Comment: What is `//` doing here?

Answer (score 7):

Get current date time attributes:

```
import datetime

currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()

print ("Current Year is: %d" % currentDT.year)
print ("Current Month is: %d" % currentDT.month)
print ("Current Day is: %d" % currentDT.day)
print ("Current Hour is: %d" % currentDT.hour)
print ("Current Minute is: %d" % currentDT.minute)
print ("Current Second is: %d" % currentDT.second)
print ("Current Microsecond is: %d" % currentDT.microsecond)


#!/usr/bin/python
import time;

ticks = time.time()
print "Number of ticks since "12:00am, Jan 1, 1970":", ticks
```

Answer (score 7):

### There are a lot of methods for getting current time in python in different formats.

I have listed all, you can use them according to your needs.

### **By Datetime method**

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

> Output: Current Time = 07:41:19

### Current time using time module

```
import time

t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
print(current_time)
```

> Tue Jul 12 10:37:46 2022

### Want time of a certain timezone?  try this.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# Get the timezone object for New York
tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 

# Get the current time in New York
datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)

# Format the time as a string and print it
print("NY time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

# Get the timezone object for London
tz_London = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')

# Get the current time in London
datetime_London = datetime.now(tz_London)

# Format the time as a string and print it
print("London time:", datetime_London.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

> NY time: 03:45:16

> London time: 08:45:16

### UTC(Coordinated Universal Time)

```
from datetime import datetime

print("UTC Time: ", datetime.utcnow())
```

> UTC Time:  2022-06-20 11:10:18.289111

### ISO Format

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

x = dt.now().isoformat()
print('Current ISO:', x)
```

> Current ISO: 2022-06-20T17:03:23.299672

### EPOCH time

```
import time

print("Epoch Time is : ", int(time.time()))
```

> Epoch Time is :  1655723915

### Getting Current GMT (Green Mean Time) using time

```
import time

# current GMT Time
gmt_time = time.gmtime(time.time())

print('Current GMT Time:\n', gmt_time)
```

> Current GMT Time:
> time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=20,
> tm_hour=11, tm_min=24, tm_sec=59, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=171, tm_isdst=0)

### FYI

- **`time`** is more accurate than `datetime` because if you don’t want ambiguity with daylight savings time (DST), use `time`.
- **`datetime`** has more built-in objects you can work with but has limited support for time zones.
- **UTC:** is a helpful reference when working with applications that require a global user to log events.
- **EPOCH:** For Operating systems and file formats.
- **ISO format:** to avoid any problems in communicating the date and time related data all around the world.
- **Greenmeantime:** The USA had already decided to base its own national time zone scheme on Greenwich and countries like Ireland, Canada also consider their reference as GMT.

Comment: What exactly is the difference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576383/10197418) for instance? Btw. you're not up-to-date; we have time zone handling in the standard library, see [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo).

Answer (score 5):

First import the datetime module from datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Then print the current time as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'

```
print(str(datetime.now())
```

To get only the time in the form 'hh:mm:ss' where ss stands for the full number of seconds plus the fraction of seconds elapsed, just do;

```
print(str(datetime.now()[11:])
```

Converting the datetime.now() to a string yields an answer that is in the format that feels like the regular DATES AND TIMES we are used to.

Answer (score 4):

The `time` module can import all sorts of time stuff, inculduing sleep and other types of stuff including - the current time type

```
import time
time.strftime("%T", time.localtime())
```

The output should look like this

```
05:46:33
11:22:56
13:44:55
22:33:44
00:00:00
```

Answer (score 4):

we can accomplish that Using datetime module

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now() #get a datetime object containing current date and time
>>> current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") #created a string representing current time
>>> print("Current Time =", current_time)
Current Time = 17:56:54
```

In addition, we can get the current time of time zome using [pytZ module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> import pytz
>>> eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
>>> eastern.zone
'US/Eastern'
>>> amsterdam = timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
>>> datetime_eu = datetime.now(amsterdam)
>>> print("Europe time::", datetime_eu.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
Europe time:: 14:45:31
```

Answer (score 4):

From Python 3.9, the [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) module can be used for getting timezones rather than using a third party library.

To get the current time in a particular timezone:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo("Europe/Amsterdam"))
```

Comment: The latest version of Python available for download is 3.8.5!  https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Sure, but in the future, when other people are reading this, that won't be the case. In fact, the first release candidate was released today: https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html

Answer (score 4):

```
import datetime

print('date='+datetime.datetime.now().__str__().split(' ')[0]+' '+'time='+datetime.datetime.now().__str__().split(' ')[1]
```

Since Qt is used extensively,

```
from PyQt5 import QDateTime
print(QDateTime.currentDateTime().__str__().split('(')[1].rstrip(')'))
```

Comment: Compared to the other answers, yours is quit long and complex

Comment: @Molitoris, it is advised to (re)use the functions available from already imported libraries. So, this is useful for those who are already working on Qt-Python.

Answer (score 4):

If you using it for django datetime sometimes won't work on server so I recommend using timezone

But for use django timezone you should set your country timezone code in your settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tashkent'
```

Then you can use it

```
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.now() // for date time

timezone.now().year // for yaer

timezone.now().month // for month

timezone.now().day // for day 

timezone.now().date // for date

timezone.now().hour // for hour

timezone.now().weekday // for minute
```

or if you want use on python

```
import time

time.strftime('%X') // '13:12:47'

time.strftime('%x') // '01/20/22'

time.strftime('%d') // '20' day

time.strftime('%m') // '01' month

time.strftime('%y') // '20' year

time.strftime('%H') // '01' hour

time.strftime('%M') // '01' minute

time.strftime('%m') // '01' second
```

Comment: Your example may cause bad programming. strftime() or now() should never be used multiple times. If you use that method at 23:59:59 your result may mix data from 2 different days.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but the question is not about using multiple times it's about getting the time. here I showed how to get not only time others too.

Answer (score 4):

If you use *pandas* a lot you can use [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html), which is the equivalent of *Python*’s [`Datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.Timestamp.now()
Out[2]: Timestamp('2022-06-21 21:52:50.568788')
```

And just the time:

```
In [3]: pd.Timestamp.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
Out[3]: '21:53:01'
```

Comment: Solution is valid, but it is an overkill to have pandas dependency just for getting current time.

Comment: Yeah, it's meant for people who use *pandas* on a daily basis and therefore already imported the library.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many complex solutions here it could be confusing for a beginner. I find this is the most simple solution to the question - as it just returns the current time as asked (no frills):

```
import datetime

time_now = datetime.datetime.now()

display_time = time_now.strftime("%H:%M")
print(display_time)
```

If you wanted more detail back than just the current time, you can do what some others have suggested here:

```
import datetime

time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(time_now)
```

Although this approach is shorter to write, it returns the current date and milliseconds as well, which may not be required when simply looking to return the current time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the time for purpose of timing function calls, then you want time.perf_counter().

```
start_time = time.perf_counter()
expensive_function()
time_taken = time.perf_counter() - start_time
print(f'expensive_function() took {round(time_taken,2)}s')
```

> time.perf_counter() → float
>
> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.
>
> New in version 3.3.
>
> ---
>
> time.perf_counter_ns() → int
>
> Similar to perf_counter(), but return time as nanoseconds.
>
> New in version 3.7.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter

Answer (score 2):

Attributes of now() can be used to get the current time in python:

```
# importing datetime module for now()
import datetime
    
# using now() to get current time
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    
# Printing attributes of now().
print ("The attributes of now() are : ")
    
print ("Year : ", end = "")
print (current_time.year)
    
print ("Month : ", end = "")
print (current_time.month)
    
print ("Day : ", end = "")
print (current_time.day)
    
print ("Hour : ", end = "")
print (current_time.hour)
    
print ("Minute : ", end = "")
print (current_time.minute)
    
print ("Second : ", end = "")
print (current_time.second)
    
print ("Microsecond : ", end = "")
print (current_time.microsecond)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code which will only show time according to your question:

```
 from datetime import datetime
 time= datetime.now()
 b = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 print(b)
```

- Used `datetime.now()` to get the current date and time.
- Then used `.strftime` to get desired value i.e time only.

[`strftime`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm) is used to retrieve the desired output or to change the default format according to our need.

Answer (score -1):

**Use this  method for UTC DateTime, local Date-Time, and convert am and pm**

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

#UTC Time
print("UTC Date and time")
epoch: datetime =datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
print(epoch)

#local date and time
print("Local Date and time")
today = datetime.now()
local_time = today.strftime("%Y-%M-%d:%H:%M:%S")
print(local_time)

#convert time to AM PM format
print("Date and time AM and PM")
now = today.strftime("%Y-%M-%d:%I:%M %p")
print(now)
```

Comment: Downvote for using the deprecated _pytz_, compounded by the fact that there also is a `datetime.timezone.utc`.

Answer (score -1):

Gets the current time and converts it to string:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
import pytz # for timezone()
import time

current_time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time2 = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei'))
current_time3 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
current_time4 = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
current_time5 = time.gmtime(time.time())

print("datetime.datetime.now():", current_time1)
print("datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')):", current_time2)
print("datetime.utcnow():", current_time3)
print("datetime.datetime.now().isoformat():", current_time4)
print('time.gmtime(time.time()): ', current_time5)
```

Comment: There are, already, 52 other answers posted. How would your code block with no commentary contribute something new to the discussion?

Answer (score -1):

If you need a time-zone aware solution. I like to use the following 5 lines of code to get the current time.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# Specify the timezone
my_time_zone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore')

# Pass the timezone to datetime.now() function
my_time = datetime.now(my_time_zone)

# Convert the type `my_time` to string with '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' format.
current_time = my_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # current_time would be something like 2023-01-23 14:09:48
```

You can find the list of all timezones using `pytz.all_timezones`.

The meaning of the symbols in `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` can be found in [geeksforgeeks Python strftime() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-strftime-function/)

Comment: Btw. we have time zone handling in the standard library, see [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo).