# How to check if the current time is in range in python?

Tags: python, datetime, range

I need to check if the current time is in timerange. The most simple case time_end > time_start:

```
if time(6,0) <= now.time() <= time(12,00): print '1'
```

But troubles begin when user enters a time range when the end time is smaller than the start time, e.g. "23:00 - 06:00". A time like '00:00' will be in this range. About 5 years ago I wrote this PHP function:

```
function checkInterval($start, $end)
  {    
    $dt = date("H:i:s");    

    $tstart = explode(":", $start);
    $tend =   explode(":", $end);
    $tnow =   explode(":", $dt);

    if (!$tstart[2])
      $tstart[2] = 0;

    if (!$tend[2])
      $tend[2] = 0;  

    $tstart = $tstart[0]*60*60 + $tstart[1]*60 + $tstart[2];
    $tend   = $tend[0]*60*60   + $tend[1]*60   + $tend[2];
    $tnow   = $tnow[0]*60*60   + $tnow[1]*60   + $tnow[2];

    if ($tend < $tstart)
      {
        if ($tend - $tnow > 0 && $tnow > $tstart)
          return true;
        else if ($tnow - $tstart > 0 && $tnow > $tend)
          return true;
        else if ($tend > $tnow && $tend < $tstart && $tstart > $tnow)
          return true;
        else return false;
      } else
      {
        if ($tstart < $tnow && $tend > $tnow)
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
```

Now I need to do the same thing, but I want to make it good looking. So, what algorithm should I use to determine if the current time '00:00' is in *reversed* range e.g. `['23:00', '01:00']`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The Python solution is going to be much, much shorter.

```
def time_in_range(start, end, x):
    """Return true if x is in the range [start, end]"""
    if start <= end:
        return start <= x <= end
    else:
        return start <= x or x <= end
```

Use the `datetime.time` class for `start`, `end`, and `x`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start = datetime.time(23, 0, 0)
>>> end = datetime.time(1, 0, 0)
>>> time_in_range(start, end, datetime.time(23, 30, 0))
True
>>> time_in_range(start, end, datetime.time(12, 30, 0))
False
```

Comment: if start=today[10:00], end=tomorrow[10:00], and x = 11:00 then `start <= x <= end = False`!!!

Comment: @PauloScardine: You have to choose how to interpret it: whether [10:00, 10:00] has length 0 or 24 hours.  Either interpretation is fine.  In other words, you say that `start < end`, but I chose `start <= end` and there is no obvious reason to choose one or the other.

Comment: The whole concept of comparing times without dates is fragile if you are crossing the barrier between days.

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example, what if you run a store that is open 7 days a week from 7am - 1am?  This is exactly the kind of function you'd need to figure out if the store is open.

Comment: The question asked about current time, but it looks to me datetime.time(23, 30, 0) is not

Comment: @ZhiyuanChen: That’s test code. If used the current time in test code, it would give different answers depending on what time you run the test, which is not what you want.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks for replying, but wouldn't it be easier if you just add datetime.datetime.now().time()? It tooks me a few minitus to find it at other places

Comment: @ZhiyuanChen: I don’t think this is the right place to add that information. That information can be found on a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python

Answer (score 16):

## Date/time is trickier than you think

Calculations involving date/time can be very tricky because you must consider timezone, leap years, day-light-savings and lots of corner cases. There is an [enlightening video from the talk by Taavi Burns at PyCon2012](http://pyvideo.org/video/946/what-you-need-to-know-about-datetimes) entitled "What you need to know about datetimes":

> [**What you need to know about datetimes**](http://pyvideo.org/video/946/what-you-need-to-know-about-datetimes):
>   `time`, `datetime`, and `calendar` from the standard library are a bit messy. Find out: what to use where and how (particularly when you have users in many timezones), and what extra modules you might want to look into.
>
> **Event**: PyCon US 2012 / **Speakers**: Taavi Burns / **Recorded**: March 10, 2012

## Use timezone-aware datetime for calculations

The concept of a `datetime.time` for tomorrow is void, because `datetime.time` lacks any date information. You probably want to convert everything to timezone-aware `datetime.datetime` before comparing:

```
def time_in_range(start, end, x):
    today = timezone.localtime().date()
    start = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.combine(today, start))
    end = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.combine(today, end))
    x = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.combine(today, x))
    if end <= start:
        end += datetime.timedelta(days=1) # tomorrow!
    if x <= start
        x += datetime.timedelta(days=1) # tomorrow!
    return start <= x <= end
```

Comment: Thank. I have not test, but your explanation is clear for me. Good morning.