# Check if current current hour is available in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I have a variable with the operating time of a store:

```
t = '08:00-17:00'
```

Now, i need to check if the store is open now:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print strftime("%H:%M", gmtime())
#11:26
```

What is the most adequate way to make this? As side note, i can have `t` in minutes, or something more convenient.

Comment: why a list? Can you have more than one element start/end times in it?

Comment: @AnandSKumar No, I can't.  question updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if the current time is in range in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747974/how-to-check-if-the-current-time-is-in-range-in-python)

Comment: @user299008t4  hello batter u make the list like t = ['08:00', '17:00'],  tt = strftime("%H:%M")  
 if tt in t: true else: false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to convert the current time into string, you should rather [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the `t` into two different times, and then convert them into `datetime.datetime.time` objects using `datetime.datetime.strptime()` , and then compare that with the time component on `datetime.datetime.now()` . Example -

```
import datetime
t = '08:00-17:00'
times = t.split('-')
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(times[0],'%H:%M').time()
end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(times[1],'%H:%M').time()
if start_time <= datetime.datetime.now().time() <= end_time:
    #Do you logic
```

Demo -

Closed time -

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = '08:00-17:00'
>>> times = t.split('-')
>>> start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(times[0],'%H:%M').time()
>>> end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(times[1],'%H:%M').time()
>>> if start_time <= datetime.datetime.now().time() < end_time:
...         print("Shop open")
... 
>>>
```

Open time -

```
>>> t = '08:00-18:00'
>>> times = t.split('-')
>>> start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(times[0],'%H:%M').time()
>>> end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(times[1],'%H:%M').time()
>>> if start_time <= datetime.datetime.now().time() < end_time:
...         print("Shop open")
...
Shop open
>>>
```

With this method even minutes are supported, you can change the format used to convert the `time` to a `time` object and support upto microseconds if you so wish.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you need to convert the *t* to a comparable value, such as a integer, so:

```
storeOpen, storeCloses = '08h00-17h00'.split('-')
```

This will split the string *'08h00-17h00'* into:

```
storeOpen => '08h00'
storeCloses => '17h00'
```

After that, you should transform the *storeOpen* and *storeCloses* into integer:

```
storeOpenHour, storeOpenMinutes = storeOpen.split('h') #splits the storeOpen into two
#converts to integer
storeOpenHour = int(storeOpenHour)
storeOpenMinutes = int(storeOpenMinutes)
#you should repeat the same process to storeClose
```

And then you just compare them:

```
if (nowMinutes > storeOpenMinutes and nowHour > storeOpenHour) and (nowMinutes < storeCloseMinutes and nowHour < storeCloseHour):
    println "is open!"
```