# Current time within the range

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to find the Time which is an hour head of current system time in python, for example if current time is 2:00 the end time should be 3:00 so that i can compare that my current time is within the range of the time period.Actually I need to carry out a task only during the time period ,So can someone help me!

Comment: So you need to find the timestamp 1 hour ahead of the currrent time.?/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the current time is in range in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747974/how-to-check-if-the-current-time-is-in-range-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime.now()` to get the current time, save it, call `datetime.now()` again when you need to check the time and subtract it by the starting time to get a `timedelta` to check if it's less than 1 hour:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = datetime.now()
while datetime.now() - start <= timedelta(hours=1):
    do_work()
```

Answer (score 0):

@blhsing is a good answer but there is a simpler and cost-effective way:

```
import time

end = time.clock() + 3600  # add hour

while time.clock() < end:
  ...
```