# Python bins every 20 minutes

Tags: python

I have a time field that goes from 07:00 to 21:00. I want to make bins of 20 minutes, is there something like this in python:

```
07:00 - 07:20
07:20 - 07:40
07:40 - 08:00
08:00 - 08:20
08:20 - 08:40
08:40 - 09:00
09:00 - 09:20
09:20 - 09:40
09:40 - 10:00
```

Comment: Yes, use the standard [**`datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library, particularly [**`timedelta`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: The accepted answer here does a pretty good job: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747974/how-to-check-if-the-current-time-is-in-range-in-python

Comment: This question might help: [time - Rounding up to nearest 30 minutes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723150/4996248). Your binning is determined by the rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to easily do this with pd.cut, for example, if your time always ranges from 7:00-21:00, binned every 20 minutes means 3 per hour * 14 hours = 42 bins. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html

`df['binned_hours'] = pd.cut(df.timestamp.dt.hour, bins=42)`