# How to check if current time is between a certain time period?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to check if the current time is between a certain time period,in this case between 10:00pm to 11:00pm but running into below error,any guidance on how to fix this?

```
import datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

if '22:00' <= current_time <= '23:00':
    print "current time is between 10:00pm to 11:00pm"
else:
    print "current time is NOT between 10:00pm to 11:00pm"
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datetime_script.py", line 4, in <module>
    if '22:00' <= current_time <= '23:00':
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to str
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the current time is in range in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747974/how-to-check-if-the-current-time-is-in-range-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the hour field using `current_time.hour` which returns an`int` which implies that it should not be compared with `str`.

You can do therefore:

```
import datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

if 22<= current_time.hour <=23:
    print ("current time is between 10:00pm to 11:00pm")
else:
    print ("current time is NOT between 10:00pm to 11:00pm")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that Python lets you do arithmetic and comparisons with `datetime` objects.
You appear only to be concerned about hours and minutes, so just get these from the current time to create a `datetime.time` object, and compare these with similar objects denoting 22:00h and 23:00h.

```
import datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
now = datetime.time(current_time.hour, current_time.minute)
if datetime.time(22, 0) <= now <= datetime.time(23, 0):
    print "current time is between 10:00pm to 11:00pm":
else:
    print "current time is NOT between 10:00pm to 11:00pm"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Just convert it to string.

```
import datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
# use the str function
if '22:00' <= str(current_time) <= '23:00':
    print ("current time is between 10:00pm to 11:00pm")
else:
    print ("current time is NOT between 10:00pm to 11:00pm")
```