# How to assign time objects to bins?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, comparison-operators

I have a list of times that I need to assign to time windows (7, 9, 12, 15, 18) to make sure each time window is covered by an element in my list.

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime

def nearest(items, target):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - target))

time_list = [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 7, 30), 
             datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 9, 0), 
             datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 16, 0), 
             datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 18, 30), 
             datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 21, 30), 
             datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 12, 30), 
             datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 19, 0), 
             datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 0, 0), 
             datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 14, 30)]

target_times = [datetime.combine(date.today(),time(i,0)) for i in range(6,19,3)]
coverage = [abs(nearest(time_list, t)-t)<time(1,30) for t in target_times]
```

Desired output:

```
[True, True, True, True, True]
```

This currently returns a "<" error, which I can get around, but I am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish what I want to do.  I have numpy and scipy libraries available and can probably get others.

Comment: Your desired output has 5 entries in the list, which matches the target_times ... So are you looking to see if any elements of `time_list` are in _any_ bin of `target_times`?

Comment: I want to know if each of the `target_times` is covered by one of the `time_list` elements

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that I put together based on this SO question [How to check if the current time is in range in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747974/how-to-check-if-the-current-time-is-in-range-in-python).  It works but I wonder if there is a better solution out there.

```
def time_in_range(start, end, x):
    today = timezone.localtime().date()
    start = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(today, start))
    end = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(today, end))
    x = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(today, x))
    if end <= start:
        end += timedelta(days=1) # tomorrow!
    if x <= start:
        x += timedelta(days=1) # tomorrow!
    return start <= x <= end

downloaded = [False, False, False, False, False]
times = [time(i,0) for i in [5,8,10,13,16,20]]
for i in range(5):
    for start_time in start_times:
        if time_in_range(times[i], times[i+1], start_time):
            downloaded[i] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your immediate question is that you are trying to compare a `timedelta` ob object to a `time` object. In this case you would want to create a `timedelta` object like so:

```
timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
```

Instead of

```
time(1,30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) here; because it has built-in ways of dealing with bins and intervals.

In this case, you have four (4) time intervals:

1. [7 to 9)
2. [9 to 12)
3. [12 to 15)
4. [15 to 18)
5. ...and is there supposed to be another interval for 18 to 24?

The "[" means inclusive, and the ")" is exclusive.

You can load `time_list` into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(time_list,columns=['timestamp']) # `columns` is how you name the column(s)
```

Then, the reason I suggest pandas is that it has a helpful function called [`.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) which bins values.

```
>>> bins = [7, 9, 12, 15, 18]
>>> pd.cut(df['timestamp'].dt.hour,bins=bins).unique().dropna().sort_values()
[(7, 9], (9, 12], (12, 15], (15, 18]]
```

You can then test for the appropriate length of the result of the above operation like this (the subtraction of 1 is because with five bins:

```
>>> covered_intervals = _ # an underscore gets the most recent value in the interpreter
>>> len(covered_intervals) == len(bins) - 1
True
```

And if you want a list of booleans you can do:

```
result = []
for i in covered_intervals:
    if i.left in bins:
        result.append(True)
    else:
        result.append(False)
```