# Python get current time in right timezone

Tags: python, time, timezone

Right now I use

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%X"))
```

to display the current time as a string.
Problem is, my computer is running in `Europe/Berlin` time zone, and the offset of +2 to UTC is not accounted here.
Instead of `19:22:26` it should display `21:22:26`
Also different to the other answers I found here, I do not store it by calling

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10, 18, 44, 59, 193982, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

but

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

so I tried (and failed) the following:

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
 ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

#### Edit:

## Answer

*Can't post as answer, as this question is marked closed*

The server I had this issue with doesn't exists any longer.
Anyway, here are some other things worth checking:

- Is the timezone of your server/system set up correctly?

  - VMs or docker containers might be out of sync with the host, that's worth checking.
- Is the time on that computer correct? You don't ended up with +2 hours after changing the timezone?

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61221/discussion-between-luckydonald-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: related: [How to get current time in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/415511/4279)

Comment: We can directly use `pytz` MODULE

Comment: @champion-runner The one I already imported above?

Comment: Ok that I just saw **Example**- `tz_London = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
datetime_London = datetime.now(tz_London)
print("London time:", datetime_London.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: I wonder if people are actually upvoting my "Answer" above, as being useful.

Comment: Or just the question, saying "me too got this problem"

Comment: Just ran into this issue due to a bug in Python 3.6+. https://bugs.python.org/issue30062. I'm now using: datetime.datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Europe/Amsterdam")). It's a bit of a hack but alas the TZ variable as I have it set can't be used directly by ZoneInfo(...).

Comment: This was made a duplicate of the other question although only here, I found the plain pytz solution. The other answer only convinced me of not using any local time with pytz at all because of the seasonal time shifts. But for someone who really just wants to show the current time of the place, why not using this pytz way here? Reopen?

Comment: @questionto42: I'd love to have this reopened and allow others than @[jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/jfs) to send in answers (jfs then voted to close this for others to answers, thus remaining the only answer to get upvoted on )

Comment: I cannot find a button to vote Reopen. Cannot you just vote for Reopen? You would get my vote, then we had already two. I do not think that the user jfs did that only to make this a unique answer, though, but I would vote for Reopen for another reason, anyway.

Answer (score 249):

To get the current time in the local timezone as a naive datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
naive_dt = datetime.now()
```

If it doesn't return the expected time then it means that your computer is misconfigured. You should fix it first (it is unrelated to Python).

To get the current time in UTC as a naive datetime object:

```
naive_utc_dt = datetime.utcnow()
```

To get the current time as an aware datetime object in Python 3.3+:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

utc_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc) # UTC time
dt = utc_dt.astimezone() # local time
```

To get the current time in the given time zone from the tz database:

```
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
berlin_now = datetime.now(tz)
```

It works during DST transitions. It works if the timezone had different UTC offset in the past i.e., it works even if the timezone corresponds to multiple tzinfo objects at different times.

Comment: @AlexanderKellett:  I don't see `pytz` being deprecated ([the latest release is Feb 1, 2021](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/#history)) `pytz` is a battle tested library with a known behavior in complex corner cases. There are multiple other timezone libraries with different tradeoffs (e.g., correctness vs. easy-of-use vs. performance). Now, having the tz (zoneinfo) library  right in the stdlib is wonderful and if it works for your use case, use it.

Comment: `If it doesn't return the expected time then it means that your computer is misconfigured`. What is the program is hosted on some remote server? In that case, won't `datetime.now()` give local time of the remote server?

Comment: @Jdeep: naturally, "local" refers to the computer where the code runs.

Comment: What if I don't know the users timezone. How do I get it then?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pytz/, PYTZ is not deprecated, the last release was on October 31, 2022.