# how to set timezone to eastern for DateTime module in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm utilizing the datetime module to produce the current date. However, when I run this after 7PM, the current date becomes tomorrow's date.

I'm not sure how to set the time zone for the following module

```
from datetime import *
print date.today()
```

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) but have not found how to set this yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your date is a "naive" datetime, it doesn't have a timezone (`tz=None`). 
Then you have to localize this datetime by setting a timezone. Use `pytz` module to do that.

Here is an example :

```python
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
# define date format
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
# define eastern timezone
eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
# naive datetime
naive_dt = datetime.now()
# localized datetime
loc_dt = datetime.now(eastern)
print(naive_dt.strftime(fmt))
# 2015-12-31 19:21:00 
print(loc_dt.strftime(fmt))
# 2015-12-31 19:21:00 EST-0500
```

Read [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) for more information

Comment: I updated my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

While `date` doesn't have a way to select a time zone, `datetime` does. You [need to create a subclass of tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) with the information for your desired time zone:

```
class UTC(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
```

For example, the Eastern **Standard** Time (UTC-5:00, no DST):

```
class EST(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours = -5)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "EST"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
```

After making a class for your timezone, you would then get the `date` you wanted with:

```
datetime.now(UTC()).date()
```

(Replace `UTC` with your timezone class name)

There is also a library available, [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), that would make this much easier for you.

Comment: US Eastern time is only -5 during *standard* time.  It switches to -4 when *daylight* time is in effect.  Hence the necessity for libraries like pytz.

Comment: @MattJohnson It's just an example, but I used  _EST_ for that reason. EST is always UTC-5, EDT is always UTC-4, ET switches between the two.

Comment: Exactly.  The OP asked for "eastern".  Of course they could be talking about eastern time in *australia* as well.  lol. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson I see your confusion now. I edited it to hopefully make it more clear that EST was just an example, not meant to actually be the OP's timezone.

Comment: how do you suggest to choose between EST and EDT? [Use the tz database instead: `datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/New_York')).date()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25887393/4279). It finds the correct utc offset for the current date automatically.