# Is there a way to show the amount of time spent developing a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to check the time I've spent developing a Jupyter Notebook?

I guess something like the time since the .ipynb was created (as it is constantly saved) to until the last save?

There are applications that show the amount of time that a file has been edited, so something similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the following in a cell it will probably do that on a windows system:

```
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime
completepath = sys.argv[0]
filecreationtime = os.path.getmtime(completepath)
filecreationtime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(filecreationtime)
now = datetime.now()
str(now - filecreationtime)
```

I am using a Linux system and it seems that creation date is not really accessible as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501288/4288043)

Maybe there is a variable that can be somehow written into the .ipynb file at creation to get around this.

Comment: Thanks @cardamom, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @cardamom that pointed me in the right direction.  I added this to a cell to get the name of the notebook into nb_name

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"')
```

Then this into another cell, and it seems to give me the answer...just a little formatting needed.

```
# Get the path from
path = !echo %cd%

# Combine the path and filename
completepath = path[0] + '\\' + nb_name

filecreationtime = os.path.getatime(completepath)
filecreationtime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(filecreationtime)

now = datetime.now()
print(f'Notebook: {nb_name}')
print(f'At path: {path[0]}')
print(f'Dev Time: {str(now - filecreationtime)}')
```

The thing is, it doesn't seem completly correct as one hour is added.  I'm using windows, so I guess it must be down to the os.path.getctime.

Comment: It's probably this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25887393/4288043 they refer to `datetime.datetime.now()` as the 'naive' time, I think if you care about that hour you have to do a bit more.