# Receiving inaccurate time from python time module?

Tags: python, time

I am a beginner in programming and I was messing around with the time module in python, as I recently got a raspberry pi and want to start doing some projects. I imported the time module, and just made a loop to print out the time every second. The code runs correctly, but the time given is not accurate to my location. Currently, it is the 14th and a Friday, around 9 pm, but it is returning the 15th a Saturday, with 0 hours and 10 minutes. Does anyone know how I can obtain the correct time?

I tried a couple of the different functions to receive the current time like .localtime() and .gmtime() but they're all the same.

```py
import time 


while(True):

    thisTime = time.gmtime()

    print(time.asctime(thisTime))

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: As for setting the clock correctly on raspberry it is rather offtopic on Stack Overflow

Comment: For that the best place is https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and check out this post, I think this is your solution:

[Python get current time in right timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837452/python-get-current-time-in-right-timezone)

So assuming your computer's time is configured correctly, you could use this:

```
from datetime import datetime
naive_dt = datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what else you've tried, although the following should work:

```
localtime = time.localtime()
print(time.asctime(localtime))
```

↳ https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime