# Adding Asia/Singapore Time stamp as the first column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to add an Asia/Singapore timestamp as the first column of the following pandas dataframe,and name it as 'sdc_sequence_id'.

```
id   col1    col2
01    A       B
02    C       D
03    E       F
```

expected dataframe :

```
sdc_sqeuence_id       id     col1    col2
2002-10-27 12:00:00   01      A      B
2002-10-27 12:00:02   02      C      D
2002-10-27 12:00:02   03      E      F
```

I tried doing this

```
df2['sdc_squence_id'] = df2['sdc_squence_id'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Singapore'
```

But this is giving me a key error..
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the current Asia/Singapore datetime ? This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837452/python-get-current-time-in-right-timezone) might help you

Comment: yes: current Asia/Singapore datetime

Comment: I tried do that but i am not being able to add a new timestamp column

Comment: This works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas

Comment: @Kishan : yeah how do i add timestamp datatype column into that ?

Comment: Check the answers in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**:

```
df["sdc_squence_id"] = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore')), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**Explanations**:

1. Get the local time in a specific timezone:

   - Use the [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) to get timezone:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore')
```

- This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837452/python-get-current-time-in-right-timezone) explains in details how to get local time

```
asia_time = datetime.now(tz)
```

2. Format local time as you want:

   - The [`datetime.date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) does the job
   - This [tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) explains how to handle datetime format in details

```
formated_datetime = datetime.strftime(asia_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

3. Add the new column to the panda `dataframe`:

   - This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas) explains how to achieve it.

```
df["sdc_squence_id"] = formated_datetime
```

**Code**

```
# Import modules
import pandas as pd
# Get local timezone time
import pytz
# Create datetime object
from datetime import datetime


tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore')
print(tz)
# Asia/Singapore

asia_time = datetime.now(tz)
print(asia_time)
# 2020-03-24 17:22:37.409483+08:00

# Format datetime
formated_datetime = datetime.strftime(asia_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# 2020-03-24 17:22:37

# Create new column
df["sdc_squence_id"] = formated_datetime
print(df)
#    id col1 col2       sdc_squence_id
# 0   1    A    B  2020-03-24 17:22:37
# 1   2    C    D  2020-03-24 17:22:37
# 2   3    E    F  2020-03-24 17:22:37
```