# Parse date and time from string with time zone using Arrow

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, arrow-python

I have

```
import arrow
s = '2015/12/1 19:00:00'
tz = 'Asia/Hong_Kong'
```

How can I parse this with Arrow such that I get an Arrow object with the time zone `tz`?  The following defaults to UTC time.

```
In [30]: arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss')
Out[30]: <Arrow [2015-12-01T19:00:00+00:00]>
```

I know the `.to` function but that converts a time zone and but doesn't allow me to change to time zone.

Comment: In arrow doc i see that the constructor works like : "class arrow.arrow.Arrow(year, month, day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None)". Is that enough for your problem? It actually returns an arrow object with you desired tz.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss', tzinfo=tz)
```

If you are also using dateutil, this works as well:

```
arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss', tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz(tz))
```

So does this:

```
arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss').replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz(tz))
```

Comment: This works! Just out of curiosity, is it possible to do the same with pytz? I get some weird results:

`In [7]: arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss').replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(tz))

Out[7]: <Arrow [2015-12-01T19:00:00+07:37]>`

Comment: Not sure, but I think arrow is better aligned with dateutil than pytz.

Comment: @mchangun: the correct way to parse the time if you don't want to ignore errors silently: `pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong').localize(datetime.strptime(s, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), is_dst=None)`

Comment: @mchangun: btw, I see that even after two years of development [`arrow` still fails to convert utc datetime to a named timezone, convert utc time to local timezone, and round-trip timestamp -> named timezone -> utc](https://gist.github.com/zed/4127162)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Do you have a recommendation for a better date time library?

Comment: @mchangun: "better" depends on your application. I use `pytz` but it might too low-level for most applications. Though all you need is to understand why pytz introduces `localize()`, `normalize()` methods, to use it correctly.

Comment: @EricDuminil - Updated my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Sorry for the harsh comment. I was disappointed by the API, not by your answer. It looks good now

Comment: No problem.  It was a very old answer.  Not sure if that was the only API at the time or not.  Also, did you know that Python 3.9+ has zoneinfo built in now?  You probably don't need time zone support from a library anymore.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint: I'll check the new API. I wanted to use arrow because it makes it easy to "humanize" a datetime, something like "in 2 hours" or "3 days ago".

Answer (score 12):

I'm not qualified yet to add a comment and would just like to share a bit simpler version of the answer with timezone str expression.

```
s = '2015/12/1 19:00:00'
tz = 'Asia/Hong_Kong'
arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss').replace(tzinfo=tz)
```

or simply local timezone:

```
arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss').replace(tzinfo='local')
```

or specified ISO-8601 style:

```
arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss').replace(tzinfo='+08:00')
```

Comment: I don't understand why `arrow.get` uses UTC as default, and not the local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me as of 0.10.0:

```py
import arrow
s = '2015/12/1 19:00:00'
tz = 'Asia/Hong_Kong'

arrow.get(s, 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm:ss', tzinfo=tz)
# <Arrow [2015-12-01T19:00:00+08:00]>
```

However, `arrow.get('2018-01-29 14:46', tzinfo='US/Central')` (i.e. without the format string) ignores the `tzinfo` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Per the current [documentation](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-arrow.factory), you can also provide a default timezone for `arrow.get()`, e.g.:

```
s = '2015/12/1 19:00:00'
tz = 'Asia/Hong_Kong'
arrow.get(s, tzinfo=tz)
```

However, as of right now (version 0.12.1) there is a shortcoming where that doesn't work for string-based date parsing. Fortunately, this [has been fixed](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/pull/516), so the next release of Arrow will integrate this fix.