# Inserting datetime into database using pyscopg2 and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm having trouble inserting a datetime stamp into a sql database using the insert statement with pyscopg2.

What the code below does is every time the button is pushed, it should insert a row into the database containing the buildingID(which is just text) and the date and time when the button was pressed.

I just can't figure out how to insert the current date and time.

```
# Inserts data into local database
def insertLocalDB():
    # Open a cursor to perform database operations
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (buildingID,datetime) VALUES(%s,%s)",
    ("01", datetime))  #HAS TO BE CURRENT DATE AND TIME
    # Make the changes to the database persistant
    conn.commit()
    # Close communication with the database
    cur.close()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While you certainly *could* insert a *Python* datetime into a row via *psycopg2* -- you would need to create a `datetime` object set to the current time, which can be done [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python) or via modules such as [Delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) -- since you just want the current time, I would just leave that up to *Postgres* itself.

e.g.

```
def insertLocalDB():
    # Open a cursor to perform database operations
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (buildingID,datetime) VALUES(%s, now() )",
    ("01", ))
    # Make the changes to the database persistant
    conn.commit()
    # Close communication with the database
    cur.close()
```

[`now()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) returns the current time as a `timestamp with time zone` type, and will be run on the server side after the first `%s` is replaced by *psycopg2* (via *libpq*) by `01`.

Also note that the *tuple* of args must have a trailing comma since it has just one element, else it won't be an actual *tuple*.