# Comparing wall time and resource usage across different programming environments

Tags: python, c++, matlab, processing-efficiency, resource-monitor

Is there a particular software resource monitor that researchers or academics use to compare execution time and other resource usage metrics between programming environments? For instance, if I have a routine in C++, python and another in Matlab, that are all identical in function and similar implantations -how would I make an objective, measurable result comparison as to which was the most efficient process. Likewise is it a tool that could also analyze performance between versions of the same code to track improvements in processing efficiency. Please try to answer this question without generalizations like "oh, C++ is always more efficient than python and python will always be more efficient than Matlab."

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to write tests. Get current time before actual algo starts, and get current time after it ends. There are ways to do that in [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python) and [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clock.html)
You must not think of results as they are 100% precision because of system scheduling process etc, though it is a good way to compare before-after results. 
Good way to get more precision results is to run your code multiple times.