# Timestamp firebase in python - argument in firebase.put()

Tags: python, datetime, firebase

Im new to python and trying to insert the date/time into my firebase.put Im unsure of what this should be and would appreciate some help. Ive tried this, strip() and a couple other unsuccessful things. Please help! Thank you

```
from firebase import firebase
import time
import datetime

whattime = datetime.datetime.now()
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('my_firebase_link',None)

result = firebase.put('/user',str(whattime),'testing')
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches for timestamps in Firebase, the local machine one and Firebase's own timestamp, the following examples demonstrate each one.

Both examples will require to import the following modules:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import json
import time #For the first example only
```

In this example we use the built in time module from Python (the datetime module works the same). The value from time.time() will be stored as a float and you should convert it back into a date object when you read it back from Firebase.

```
def send_message(message, username):

    my_data = dict()
    my_data["message"] = message
    my_data["username"] = username
    my_data["timestamp"] = time.time()

    json_data = json.dumps(my_data).encode()

    try:
        loader = urllib.request.urlopen("https://<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>.firebaseio.com/messages.json", data=json_data)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        message = json.loads(e.read())
        print(message["error"])
    else:
        print(loader.read())
```

This example will use Firebase internal timestamp. The value {".sv": "timestamp"} is interpreted by Firebase and it's converted into a timestamp when the request is processed.

```
def send_message(message, username):

    my_data = dict()
    my_data["message"] = message
    my_data["username"] = username
    my_data["timestamp"] = {".sv": "timestamp"}

    json_data = json.dumps(my_data).encode()

    try:
        loader = urllib.request.urlopen("https://<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>.firebaseio.com/messages.json", data=json_data)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        message = json.loads(e.read())
        print(message["error"])
    else:
        print(loader.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

This code solved the problem for me:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate("/home/pi/Documents/gpioZero/iot-maison-firebase- adminsdk-a0c7t-666fdeb9bd.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
pir = MotionSensor(4)
led = LED(16)

def motionOn():
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'motion').document(u'test1')
    dateNow = datetime.datetime.now() 
    doc_ref.set({u'started': True,u'date': dateNow })
    led.on()
    print("On")
pir.when_activated=motionOn
```