# Measure current time in seconds?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, calendar

How can I take the current time in seconds in Python? I was using `calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())` but I'm not sure if this given value is in seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python)

Comment: Try `time` module. `import time; time.time()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
import time
print(round(time.time()))
```

Comment: also `int(time.time())` if you don't want a `float`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from datetime import datetime

sec = int(datetime.utcnow().total_seconds()) % 86400
```