# How to write function to calculate current date as time input for python script

Tags: python, date, cron

I am trying to edit my python script so that it will pull data from a database daily. Currently my script asks for a manual (raw) input of the date in the format: YYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS. *But* what I really need is for the start time to be calculated based on the current date.

This is what my script looks like now:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

starttime_str = raw_input("enter time:")  # example 2016:10:18:00:00:00
arr = starttime_str.split(':')
starttime = datetime(int(arr[0]), int(arr[1]), int(arr[2]), int(arr[3]), int(arr[4]), int(arr[5]))
```

But what I really need for the `starttime_str` to be the computer's date. So perhaps I should write a function to find the date and then calculate the time stamp? I will update the cron entry so that the script runs daily & automatically. I know I should use something like `pd.tslib.Timestamp.now()` but I don't need the whole string.

Comment: Does `datetime.datetime.now()` do it for you?

Comment: `date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pointed out in the comment section is resolved by using split() fuction in the following code

```
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 from pandas import DataFrame
 import pandas as pd
 from io import StringIO

 starttime_str = str(datetime.today()).replace("-", ":")
 arr = starttime_str.split(':')
 starttime = datetime(int(arr[0]), int(arr[1]), int(arr[2].split(' ')[0]), int(arr[2].split(' ')[1]), int(arr[3]), int(float(arr[4])))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

starttime_str = str(datetime.today()).replace("-", ":")
arr = starttime_str.split(':')
starttime = datetime(int(arr[0]), int(arr[1]), int(arr[2]), int(arr[3]), int(arr[4]), int(arr[5]))
```

Comment: Hm I get the error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16 20'`

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot there is space character in the date and hour. you can replace that space first before split starttime_str and you also need to use `float(arr[5])`:

`starttime_str = str(datetime.today()).replace("-", ":").replace(" ", ":")`
`arr = starttime_str.split(':')`
`starttime = datetime(int(arr[0]), int(arr[1]), int(arr[2]), int(arr[3]), int(arr[4]), float(arr[5]))`