# time.time() and datetime.datetime.now() does not get current time when used in a descriptor

Tags: python

When coding in Python, the common way to get the current time is `time.time()` or `datetime.datetime.now()`. But I never doubted their result until this code:

```
import time

class A(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print '__get__ is run'
        return time.time()
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('let me set, but i will not', value)

class C(object):
    a = A()

c1 = C()
c2 = C()
print(c1.a)
c1.a = time.time()
print(c1.a)
print('-' * 20)
print(c2.a)
```

The result of this code is:

```
__get__ is run
1512115138.19
('let me set, but i will not', 1512115138.188)
__get__ is run
1512115138.19
--------------------
__get__ is run
1512115138.19
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

What happened on earth? Why do these three `time.time()` calls get the same result?
The same result is for `datetime.datetime.now()`. And the same result in python 2 and python 3.
I can't find some python technique to explain it.

Comment: This should help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is a problem about precision, check this [link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20time%0Aclass%20A%28object%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__get__%28self,%20instance,%20owner%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28'__get__%20is%20run'%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20time.time%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__set__%28self,%20instance,%20value%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28'let%20me%20set,%20but%20i%20will%20not',%20value%29%0A%0Aclass%20C%28object%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20a%20%3D%20A%28%29%0A%0Ac1%20%3D%20C%28%29%0Ac2%20%3D%20C%28%29%0Aprint%28c1.a%29%0Ac1.a%20%3D%20time.time%28%29%0Aprint%28c1.a%29%0Aprint%28'-'%20*%2020%29%0Aprint%28c2.a%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=25&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false). You can see a more precise output:

```
__get__ is run
1512115904.6300762
let me set, but i will not 1512115904.631677
__get__ is run
1512115904.6346197
--------------------
__get__ is run
1512115904.6372328
```

Comment: So it is:) Thank you!