# How to insert today's Date and Time on Dash App (Python Framework)

Tags: python, date, time, plotly-dash

I am creating a python app (DASH app) check what is dash here (https://youtu.be/5BAthiN0htc) and I would like insert **Today's DATE and TIME**.
Could you please help me on adding it to my app?

Thanks,

Comment: @jezrael, any tip and trick?

Comment: What is dash app, what do you mean by inserting date. Please explain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python)

Comment: @vumaasha, check this https://youtu.be/5BAthiN0htc to know about dash.

Comment: @Rakesh, you proposed duplicate solution is not what I want, I will edit my question. I want to display current date and time on Dash app.

Comment: @Rakesh, if you find similar question please mantain your downvote.Thanks.

Comment: Probably you will get more feedback if you add `plotly` tag.

Comment: @Georgy, I already fixed myself. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: @Rakesh, please, see below the code what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I provide a solution for those who may have similar problem:

The code should be similar to below code and put it inside the DIV of your Dash App ( app.layout = html.Div([ ). I put atributes to allow you customize the format of display.

```
import datetime

html.Div([
                html.H1(
                datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), style=
{'opacity': '1','color': 'white', 'fontSize': 12}),
                html.H1(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), style=
{'opacity': '1','color': 'white', 'fontSize': 12}),
            ],

        ], 

        html.Br([]),


2018-02-24
19:33:39
```