# how to compare between now time and chosen time

Tags: python, time, compare

i am working with raspberry pi (python), i wanted to start reading a file at specific time of the the day, but the problem every time i try to compare between real time and my required time i don't get any thing and sometimes i get. typeerror:c an't compare datetime.time to str

```
import datetime

import time

timee = (" %s" %time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))


t = datetime.time(14, 30, 00)

t1 = datetime.time(15, 30, 00)

if (timee >= t and timee <= t1):
    print ('this is right')
```

Comment: Using local time like this is ok, unless your area uses daylight saving time. If that's the case, you need to make sure that a daylight saving changeover doesn't occur in the time interval between `t` and `t1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just the `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

t = datetime.time(14, 30, 00)
t1 = datetime.time(15, 30, 00)

if (t <= datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()) <= t1):   #Check if current time is between t and t1
    print ('this is right')
```

Comment: thank you sir its exactly what i want

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the strftime method you are using. It returns a string of the time and not a datetime.time object.
Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python) for getting the current time.
Reproducing what is in the answer:
`datetime.datetime.now().time()`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (another one is using `datetime.now()` function for getting current time):

```
import datetime
import time

# timee = ("%s" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
timee = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # no need to format it as string here

t = datetime.time(14, 30, 00)
t1 = datetime.time(15, 30, 00)

if t <= datetime.time(*[int(i) for i in timee.split(':')]) <= t1:
    print ('this is right')
```

Prints `this is right` if time is between 14:30:00 and 15:30:00 (included).

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. Why parse a string at all?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Because `timee` is string, and I want to convert it to time for comparison. Maybe OP gets the timee-like values from somewhere else...

Comment: Look at the code: `timee` is created right there - what for?

Comment: The OP says "i wanted to start reading a file at specific time of the the day" so `timee` is supposed to be the current time. It doesn't come from somewhere else.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, OP accepted different answer that suited for him more. That doesn't mean this answer is incorrect.