# How to get a timestamp?

Tags: python

Is there any function in python similar to `new Date().getTime()` in javascript? I want to get timestamp like this:
`1569046436.991`

Comment: Near-duplicate: [How to get the current time in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/415511)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the time module and use time.time().

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: time.time()
Out[2]: 1569048420.49872
```

This gives you the Unix epoch time which is the same format that new Date().getTime() returns in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [datetime.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now().timestamp())
>> 1569054370.358652
```

or [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time)

```
import time
print(time.time())
>> 1569054370.359672
```