# How to create a ROS publisher that sends the actual wall clock time to the subscriber?

Tags: python, time, ros, publisher

I am having an issue figuring out how to write a publisher node (ROS Python) that will send the subscriber the actual time (IE: 12:46) which I need to do for my homework. I need to publish the actual time, so that the subscriber can use that time, and a difference in time requested through a service to calculate the time somewhere else in the world. (Ie: Node1 publishes time in New York, Node2 subscribes and requests the time difference between current location-New York- and London. Node1 sends the information on the time difference to Node2. Node2 takes current time and time difference and adds them to find out the current time in London)

I have googled the issue and I cannot find any helpful information. I have found some confusing sources that say how to get the simulated time in seconds, and (maybe) the clock time in seconds, but I did not really understand what they were saying enough to use the information.

## code that I have so far: Sorry, IDK how to format it right on this website

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   from beginner_tutorials.srv import TimeDiff, TimeDifResponse

   from std_msgs.msg import Time

   import rospy

   pub = rospy.Publisher('currentTime', Time, queue_size=10)
   CurrentTime= localtime()

   def setupPublisher():
    
       rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
       rate = rospy.Rate(5) # 5hz

       while not rospy.is_shutdown():

           global CurrentTime
           CurrentTime= localtime()
           pub.publish(CurrentTime)
           rate.sleep()

   if __ name __ == "__ main __":
       setupPublisher()
```

I don't really have any code to share because I don't know how to incorporate the time. This is what I have so far, but I don't think it's right

It should publish the time to the subscriber, but I have no idea what it is doing, or what variables I should be using, or anything for that matter. We didn't learn about this in class at all.

Comment: Why don't you think it's right? What happens, what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You should be familiar with all the ROS pre-defined message types (although some are significantly more used than others), including the [std_msgs](https://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs?distro=melodic) [std_msgs/Header](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) message. It includes the std_msgs/Time message and a `frame_id` (String) term, for which you could store the location of the time.

Also, the ROS `time` type (for which there is a std_msg `Time` wrapping it), needs to be acquired from the appropriate ROS (rospy) method, not `localtime()` (although you could make the `time` from the `localtime()` if you wanted).
For more `time`/Time references, here is the [overview](https://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time), [client time libraries](https://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Client_Libraries), and [python / rospy](https://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time) specifics. The gist is the three (completely equivalent) functions:

```
rospy.Time.now() #get time as rospy.Time instance
rospy.get_rostime() #get time as rospy.Time instance, same as .now()
rospy.get_time() #get time as float secs
```

Remember the standard for the "current time" is seconds from 1970 UTC/GMT (timezone +-0). [rospy.Time](https://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rospy/html/rospy.rostime-pysrc.html#Time.now) holds to this as it uses python's [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) for the current ROS time (which is just a tuple of the seconds since and extra nanoseconds from the second). This will allow you to use the rest of the [python tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python) to format it as you wish. ROS also allows a "simulated time" with the `Clock`, as you saw, but that is a fun feature for simulation that isn't what you get by default when you use `Time` (no need to worry).

Comment: Other than the using `CurrentTime = localtime()` instead of rospy.Time, your code for writing a `Time` publisher is correct. If you have more questions on services or multiple nodes interaction/design, make a new question specifically addressing your problems (as this one only specified publishing and understanding time usage in ROS).