# How to create a ROS node that can start and stop counting based on what message the other node its subscribed to sends

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ros

I am basically trying to get a node that both publishes and subscribes.

Imagine I have two nodes, node1 publishes and count_node subscribes and publishes as well.

When node1 publishes "start count" I want count_node to start counting and publish the count value.

If node1 publishes to "stop count" while count_node is counting, I want count_node to stop the active count.

My attempt is below in code. I use ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. A similar problem is given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159046/how-to-create-a-ros-publisher-that-sends-the-actual-wall-clock-time-to-the-subsc) but the part I wanted the answer to was never answered.

My attempt thus far fails because when I receive the message to start the count the callback function calls a function (startCount) that uses a while loop to increment.

Thus, until the count it finished, count_node cannot process the message to stop the count and the stopCount function is called AFTER the count is finished, not while its counting.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Here is my attempt at count_node:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import Int32

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + ' I heard: %s', data.data)
    if (data.data=="start count"):
        startSanitization()        
    elif (data.data=="stop count"):
        stopSanitization()

def startCount():
    percent = 0

    while percent < 101 :
        rospy.loginfo(percent)
        pub.publish(percent)
        percent = percent + 1
        rate.sleep()     

def stopCount():
    percent = 0
    rospy.loginfo(percent)
    pub.publish(percent)

def listener():

    # In ROS, nodes are uniquely named. If two nodes with the same
    # name are launched, the previous one is kicked off. The
    # anonymous=True flag means that rospy will choose a unique
    # name for our 'listener' node so that multiple listeners can
    # run simultaneously.

    #check for message on Topic
    rospy.Subscriber('brwsrButtons', String, callback)

    rospy.loginfo("hello")
    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #create a unique node
    rospy.init_node('count_node', anonymous=True)
    #create a publisher object
    pub = rospy.Publisher('progress', Int32, queue_size=10)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) #10Hz
    #start the subscribing and publishing process
    listener()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your goal is to:

1. Subscribe to `brwsrButtons`, which publishes a string, whose value can be `start count` or `stop count`
2. If the value is `start count`, you want to increment `percent` value till it reaches `100` (not sure what you would like to do after that)
3. If the value is `stop count`, you want to reset `percent` to `0`
4. Publish this percent on `progress` topic

Also assuming by `startSanitisation` and `stopSanitisation` you meant `startCount` and `stopCount` methods.

This can be done by having a `global` `percent` variable, which keeps a track of the percentage. In your `callback` method, just like you check string value, also check whether percentage is less than 100, and if it is, increment it by one, if not, put a 0.
Then, in the `main` method, you have a loop which runs until you shutdown the node, which publishes `percent` to `/progress` topic.

Here's modified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#imports
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String, Int32

percent = 0

def callback(data):
    global percent
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + ' I heard: %s', data.data)
    if (data.data=="start count") and percent<100:
        percent += 1        
    elif (data.data=="stop count"):
        percent = 0 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #create a unique node
    rospy.init_node('count_node', anonymous=True)
    #create a publisher object
    rospy.Subscriber('brwsrButtons', String, callback)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('progress', Int32, queue_size=10)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) #10Hz
    #start the subscribing and publishing process
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        percentPubMsg = Int32()
        percentPubMsg.data = percent
        pub.publish(percentPubMsg)
        rate.sleep()
```

A better way is to use OOP:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#imports
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String, Int32

class NodeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #initialize node
        rospy.init_node("count_node")
        self.nodename = rospy.get_name()
        rospy.loginfo("Started node %s" % self.nodename)
        
        #vars
        self.percent = 0

        #params and ROS params
        self.rate = rospy.get_param('~rate',10)

        #subscribers
        rospy.Subscriber("brwsrButtons", String, self.callback)
        #publishers
        self.progressPub = rospy.Publisher("progress", Int32, queue_size=10)

    def callback(self, msg):
        if msg.data == 'start_count' and self.percent<100:
            self.percent += 1
        else:
            self.percent = 0

    def spin(self):
        self.r = rospy.Rate(self.rate)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            percentPubMsg = Int32()
            percentPubMsg.data = self.percent
            self.progressPub.publish(percentPubMsg)
            self.r.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """main"""
    try:
        nodeClass = NodeClass()
        nodeClass.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you, your assumptions were correct and this was helpful but I guess I didn't state it clearly; the counter should count on its own, once the message to start is received, not increment whenever a message to start is received. For example, imagine pushing and releasing a button and a display starts to count from 0 to 100. When I push the stop button the counter will stop counting and display the value it reached. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: It isn't quite clear to me. Could you add example data in your answer to explain your requirement better?

Comment: I don't really have data but I can try a different explanation, the node will subscribe to brwsrButtons and look out for either a start count or stop count message. When start count is received I want the same node to start publishing numbers counting from 0 to 100 (with a frequency of 10Hz). This should happen until it reaches 100 or receives a stop count message. (I may need a reset option later on but I need to fix this first) Another way to look at it: Imagine a timer app on your phone or PC. You press start and it starts counting until you press stop. That is what I need to do. Thanks.