# how to change SQL date in python, auto run

Tags: python, sql, filter, automation, anaconda

I am trying to read a SQL date in a query within Python and have it run on the first of every month and be filtered for that date. I know how to read in the SQL query in python but I was wondering how I specify the code to change the where `(where date = ''`) to the date I want (ex. `1-1-20` and then `2-1-20` and so on) and also have the query run automatically throughout time.

Answer (score 0):

In your script in Python you just need to query using the date of run:

```
today = datetime.today()
query_date = '{}-{}-{}'.format(today.month, 1, today.year)
```

And if you want to automate the execution, then depends on your SO. In linux you could use a cronjob.

`0 0 1 * * /path/to/script.py`

Some SO links:

[How to get the current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python)

[how to create a cron job that runs on the first day of month [duplicate]](https://serverfault.com/questions/87472/how-to-create-a-cron-job-that-runs-on-the-first-day-of-month)