# Real Time Clock(RTC) in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I am wondering about does Python has Real Time Clock which is giving us exactly year, month, day, hour, min, and second?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datetime.now()
```

Thats it.It gives the current date and time upto microseconds.
Use as you want.

Setting an alarm after 2 days.

```
alarm_time = date.today() + timedelta(days = 2)     #set alarm time 2day after today

while(date.today()!=alarm_time):                    #run loop till datetoday is not  alarm_time
    time.sleep(60*60)                               #wait for an hour then recheck time
#do here anything you want to do when alarm time has reached#
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another question. Let say if I want to set reminder for 2 days from current time, how can I do it?

Comment: @JonnyNguyen added the alarm to answer. check the changes.

Answer (score 2):

For Date Time operations in python you need to import datetime library.There different functions related to date formatting, getting current date and time etc..  Refer this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Current date and time : ")
print (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Hope the above code will do your job ...

Comment: Thank you! I have another question. Let say if I want to set reminder for 2 days from current time, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

`temp.year, temp.month, temp.day,temp.hour,temp.minute,temp.second` would give your desire values separately

```
from datetime import datetime

temp = datetime.now()
timee = "{:04d}{:02d}{:02d} {:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(temp.year, temp.month, temp.day,temp.hour,temp.minute,temp.second)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another question. Let say if I want to set reminder for 2 days from current time, how can I do it?

Comment: @Jonny Nguyen to make it too short, set you time , time.sleep, print reminder. As it is some thing completely different from your question, try your code and if there is issue just raise another question. Good luck