# Python: I'm using time value inside a module but the time is required multiple times in the program

Tags: python

Example :

### Filename: date_new.py

import time

CURRENT_TIME=time.time()

### Filename2:test1.py

import date_new

date_new.CURRENT_TIME #### 2020/04/15 05:46:14

..

..

..

date_new.CURRENT_TIME #### 2020/04/15 05:46:14 same answer both places

I want the latest time stamp

Comment: Create a small function CURRENT_TIME in date_new.py file and return time.time() and call the same from your test1.py file. In your case once time is generated it is assigned to CURRENT_TIME. Go through this file you can use time in multiple ways.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python

Comment: I have multiple variables other than CURRENT_TIME, for my test execution we call date, gmt time, month,etc. Nearly 200 such variables are defined in first file