# How to get the current time with python

Tags: python, datetime, time

How do you get the current time in python? I have seen people get the date and time, but I only want the time as a string.

For example, if the current time was 8:30, the command should output:
"8:30".

Also, how do you find what day of the week it is>

For example, if it is Tuesday hen the output should be:
2.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python)

Comment: you can use datetime module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))
```

Will return this:

```
13:29
```

To get seconds too:

```
print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am making a discord bot with python and am programing a function to remind people to go to class.

Comment: No problem! Always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
import datetime
my_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
```