# get current date regardless of system date in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the current date by below python code

```
from datetime import date
currentdate = date.today()
```

This returns me the system date, so if I try to change the system date it returns the current date based on that.
But I want to get the current date regardless of system date so that if we change the system date as well it should return me the current date.
How can I achive this in python?

Comment: are you talking about time based on your timezone kinda thing?

Comment: @GhostOps yes based on my timezone .

Comment: try pytz library then..

Comment: @GhostOps If I am not connected to internet is there any way to get currentdate?

Comment: @Tomerikoo with this approach it returns date based on system date right i do not want it to be our systemdate it should be based on timezone

Comment: @shee have you tried ```pytz```?

Comment: @GhostOps yes that return systemtime

Comment: @shee did you tried like this ```pytz.timezone('your-timezone-goes-here')``` ?

Comment: This thread already covers lot of information "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python"

Answer (score 2):

You should get current time from outer source, like

```
r = requests.get('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now').json()
print(r['currentDateTime']);
```

Comment: If I am not connected to internet is there any way to get currentdate?

Comment: then you have no outer source, and only thing you can use is system time — UTC or Local