# How to start/stop a function at specific time of the day?

Tags: python, datetime, while-loop

If I have a function that loops throughout the day denoted by:

```
def Show()
```

How can I run it so that at a particular time of the day it won't return anything?

In this instance say 13:50 to 14:20?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could just check the time using an `if` statement:

```
# import datetime module
from datetime import datetime as dt

# set to time bounds:
lower_bound = dt.time(13, 50)
upper_bound = dt.time(14, 20)
```

Then just check the time whenever the function runs:

```
now = dt.now().time()
if lower_bound < now < upper_bound:
     pass
if not (lower_boun < now < upper_bond):
     Show() #that returns something.
```

...or just put the if statements into the function itself

Check out this [question on `now()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python) and this [question on comparing time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python)

Answer improved by helpful comments of chepner and 0x5423

Comment: Why use `dt.now` at all? `lower_bound = datetime.time(13, 50)`

Comment: Tip: Python lets you [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) comparison operators, so you can write that check as `if lower_bound < now < upper_bound:`.

Comment: @chepner and 0x5453 - thanks for the suggestions. I incorporate them into the answer

Comment: I would also just negate the condition, rather than use `pass` and an `else` clause. `if not (lower_bound < now < upper_bond): Show()`. Or `if now <= lower_bound or now >= upper_bound: Show()`.

Answer (score 3):

`schedule` is an excellent module for doing all of this.  It even runs async without too much work.

https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
schedule.every(1).hours.at("06:00").do(show).tag('show', 'guest')
```

and then stop the schedule at a specific time

```
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").clear('show')
```