SSLCertificateVerifyFailed issue with Python and Slack API
I'm encountering an issue with SSL certificate verification while trying to connect my Python application to the Slack API. Here's the error message I'm receiving:
 ERROR  
.App  
to establish a connection (session id: 8964aa82-8fe9-487b-9211->badc171fc58e, error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify 
  failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1000))  
ERROR  
.App  
invoked (session id: 7d76995a-9544-40b4-8f21-8182300a0606, error:  
  SSLCertVerificationError, message: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] 
  certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1000))
DEBUG:slack_sdk.web.base_client:Sending a request - url: 
  https://slack.com/api/auth.test, query_params: {}, body_params: {}, files: 
  {}, json_body: None, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form->urlencoded', 'Authorization': '(redacted)', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.12.4 
  slackclient/3.30.0 Windows/10'}
ERROR:slack_sdk.web.base_client:Failed to send a request to Slack API 
  server: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify 
  failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1000)>
INFO:slack_sdk.web.base_client:A retry handler found: 
  ConnectionErrorRetryHandler for POST https://slack.com/api/auth.test - 
  <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: 
  certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1000)>
INFO:slack_sdk.web.base_client:Going to retry the same request: POST 
  https://slack.com/api/auth.test
ERROR:slack_sdk.web.base_client:Failed to send a request to Slack API 
  server: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify 
  failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1000)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File ">C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request>.py", line 1344, in do_open
   h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
 File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py>", line 1336, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py>", line 1382, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py>", line 1331, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py>", line 1091, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py>", line 1035, in send
    self.connect()
 File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py>", line 1477, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 
  455, in wrap_socket
   return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 
  1042, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File 
  "C:\Users\54113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 
  1320, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

Despite these efforts, I'm still facing the same issue. Could someone please advise on how to resolve this SSL certificate verification problem with Python and Slack API? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have already tried the following steps:

Ensured that my Python environment is up to date.
Checked and updated the certifi library to the latest version.
Verified the SSL certificate path in my environment and it points to the correct cacert.pem.
Checked that time and time zone are updated


It says that the certificate is expired. Check that you have the correct time on your system.

I did check that the time and time zone are correct in the Windows configuration. I'm going to edit my message by adding a more extensive log from what Python terminal indicates it might be usefull.

Since the certificate for slack.com is not expired it really is the most likely option that the time on your system is wrong or at least what python thinks about it. Please add the time as seen by your python script to your code - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-in-python how to do this. Also, please learn how to properly format code and stacktraces so that it actually is readable - see the available help.
